# Enequality with integral

Tags: integration, inequality

Let $I_n=\int\limits_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{4}} \tan^n x\,dx.$ Prove
$$\frac{1}{2n+2}<I_n<\frac{1}{2n-2}\,\,\,\text{for }\,\,\,n\ge 2$$

I get $I_n+I_{n-2}=\frac{1}{n-1}$ and checked
$ \frac16<I_2=1-\frac{\pi}{4}<\frac12$ and $\frac18<I_3=\frac{1-\ln 2}{2}<\frac14$

Then I thought that induction would go easily, but it turned out not to be so.

Comment: Taking into account that $I_n$ is decreasing you get the desired inequalities. For example ${1\over n-1}\le 2I_{n-2}.$ Hence $I_{n-2}\ge {1\over 2n-2}.$ i.e. $I_n\ge {1\over 2n+2}.$ Similarly ${1\over n-1}\ge 2I_n.$

Comment: Sorry, i haven't understand, do you deduce inequalities from decreasing only ?

Comment: @Minz Following Ryszard's comment, we know that $I_{n} \geq I_{n+1}$. So we have that $I_{n} + I_{n-2} \leq I_{n-2} + I_{n-2} = 2I_{n-2}$. Thus we've got $\frac{1}{n-1} \leq 2I_{n-2}$. The other one follows similarly.

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc, Ransplit thanks

Answer (score 3):

Over $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$, we have $0\le \tan x\le 1$. Therefore,
$$
I_n=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\tan^n xdx>\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\tan^nx\left(\frac{1+\tan^2 x}{2}\right)dx
=
\int_0^1u^n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)du=\frac{1}{2n+2}.
$$
Also, using $I_n+I_{n-2}=\frac{1}{n-1}$ and $I_{n-2}>\frac{1}{2n-2}$ altogether, will give you the upper bound for $I_n$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{4}), \tan x\in [0,1)$.  Therefore, we have $$
\tan ^{n-2} x>\tan ^n x \Rightarrow I_{n-2}>I_n \tag*{(*)} 
$$
Using the reduction formula, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_n & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan ^n x d x \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan ^{n-2} x\left(\sec ^2 x-1\right) d x \\
& =\frac{1}{n-1}-I_{n-2} \\
I_n & +I_{n-2}=\frac{1}{n-1}
\end{aligned}
$$
Using $(*)$, we deduce that $$
\begin{aligned}
& 2 I_n<I_n+I_{n-2}<2 I_{n-2} \\
\Rightarrow \quad  & \frac{1}{n+1}<2 I_n<\frac{1}{n-1}<2 I_{n-2} \\
\Rightarrow \quad  & \frac{1}{2 n+2}<I_n<\frac{1}{2 n-2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.